# RBAC privilege error while installing minikube

Tags: minikube, rhel7

I am trying to install **minikube** on RHEL 7.4 using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/. My system has password-less root set up.

The installation of docker, virtualbox, minikube, kubectl, etc goes fine, but when I run `minikube start` I get:

> Error starting cluster:  timed out waiting to elevate kube-system RBAC privileges: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings: Service Unavailable.

What can I do to get past this?

Comment: Same issue with Kubernetes v1.13.3, Minikube v0.34.1, virtualbox v6.0.4

Comment: Same issue with Kubernetes v1.14.2 on Docker 18.09.6, virtualbox v6.0.8.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem, I just updated the virtualbox to 5.2.22 r126460, and the error gone.

Before:

```
george:cloud neng$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 170.78 MB / 170.78 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E1119 11:38:49.424164   32901 start.go:297] Error starting cluster:  timed out waiting to elevate kube-system RBAC privileges: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.103:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings: dial tcp 192.168.99.103:8443: i/o timeout
```

After:

```
george:cloud neng$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file
```

Comment: Having the same issue with virtualbox 6.0.2

Comment: Same issue with Kubernetes v1.13.3, Minikube v0.34.1, virtualbox v6.0.4